# Suppress Android Studio spell check within a specific resource file

Tags: android, android-resources, lint, suppress-warnings, android-spellcheck

I have a case of a lot of UI strings in Android `strings.xml` resource files, such as `sol3`, which are not words, and which do not belong in a dictionary.  I would like to disable lint spell check for those strings, on a per-element basis, something like

```
<string someattr="nospellcheck">sol3</string>
```

and on a per-file basis, something like

```
<resources someattr="nospellcheck">...</resources>
```

Is there any way to do that?

My only solution now, is to gather the non-word stings into separate resource files with a different name, perhaps `non-words.xml`.  Then in Android Studio's **Settings**,
create a **Scope** that filters for that file name, and under

```
Editor->Inspections->Correctness->Messages
```

In both of these, there is an option to add a **Scope** (non-obvious).
Add the **Scope**, before **Everywhere Else**.

But that is horrible.  What is the right way to locally suppress spell checks in XML files?

(I got this working for .bat files under Editor->Inspections->Proofreading, but for the current issue, I only managed to change the **Message**, not make it stop appearing.)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#configuring-lint-checking-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @CommonsWare pointed to the answer.  It is very easy, and just what I was looking for.
(Web searches somehow still don't turn up the answer.  But I should have been able to figure it out from the Android Studio UI tips.)

Within the `<resources>` element, the `tools` namespace has to be defined:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

All spellchecking within that element can be disabled with the attribute

```
tools:ignore="Typos"
```

Spellchecking for an individual `<string>` child is suppressed by the same attribute.

Thanks!